# MongoDb array updating

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to update the following document in Mongodb.

```
    doc = { id : 10 , graph :[{userId:1,children:[2]},{userId:2,children:[]}]}

    db.test.insert(doc)
```

then I perform two updates:

```
db.test.update( {'id':10,'graph.userId' : 1}, { $push:{'graph.$.children':10}})

db.test.update( {'id':10,'graph.userId' : 1},{ $push:{'graph':{'userId':10,'children':[]}}})
```

(Saddly :

```
db.test.update( {'id':10,'graph.userId' : 1},{ $push:{'graph.$.children':10},$push:{'graph':{'userId':10,'children':[]}}})
```

does not work)

Is there a way to update these simultaneously ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiple keys in the modifier array stop it from working. You have to do two updates to do this if I read your shema right cos you are trying to push a new child onto the current position and push a new record into the subdocument of the parent.

The thing that stops it is the children[] setting. Mongo just does not know where to set that.

I suppose you could try:

```
db.test.update( {'id':10,'graph.userId' : 1},{ $push:{'graph.$.children':10},$pushAll:{'graph':{{'userId':10,'children':[]}}}})
```

But it is a long shot

Comment: thanks for your help,  a pitty the simultneous update does not work

Answer (score 2):

You can bundle multiple update operations together, but the only issue with what you've written in pseudo code is that the elements you're pushing belong to different arrays (graph and graph.children respectively.) This needs to be done in two pushes.

Try this:

```
db.test.update( { id:10, 'graph.userId':1 }, 
        { $push:{'graph.$.children' : 4 }, $push:{'graph' : {'userId':4,'children':[]}} } )
```

Comment: really sorry but it turns out this does  not work. I have edited the question, thanks

Comment: wont the second push override the first since they have the same key